# Ionic 2 Providers

Tags: ionic2

I am upgrading my app from `Ionic 2.0.0-beta.20` to `Ionic 2.0.0-rc.3` using [this guide](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-200-rc0-2016-09-28).

I have an issue regarding a `provider` called `RatingService`, which I am a little confused about, if anyone can assist, I would appreciate it.

**Problem**

I get the following error in `app.module.ts`.

```
[ts] Argument of type '{ declarations: any[]; imports: ModuleWithProviders[]; bootstrap: typeof IonicApp[]; entryCompone...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModule'.
       Types of property 'providers' are incompatible.
         Type '{ provide: typeof ErrorHandler; useClass: typeof IonicErrorHandler; RatingService: typeof RatingS...' is not assignable to type 'Provider[]'.
           Type '{ provide: typeof ErrorHandler; useClass: typeof IonicErrorHandler; RatingService: typeof RatingS...' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
             Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'RatingService' does not exist in type 'Provider'.
```

I think I need to make use of `provide:` and `useClass:` for each `provider`, but I'm not sure what these values should be?

**Code**

**app.module.ts**

```
  import { RatingService } from '../pages/service/ratingService';
    ...
  providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, 
    useClass: IonicErrorHandler, 
    RatingService,
    JobService, 
    UtilityService, 
    ...
```

**ratingService.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { RatingModel } from '../model/RatingModel';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http, Headers } from "@angular/http"
import { ParentService } from "../service/parentService";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class RatingService extends ParentService {

    public BASE_URI: String = super.getBaseUrl()+'/rating';

    public http: Http = null;

    constructor( @Inject(Http) http: Http) {
        super();
        this.http = http;
    }

    getRatingRange(firstResult: number, maxResults: number): Promise<RatingModel[]> {
        return new Promise<RatingModel[]>(resolve => {
            this.getRatingRangeHttpCall(firstResult, maxResults).subscribe(
                data => {
                    var ratingModels: RatingModel[] = [];
                    for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
                        var element = data[index];
                        ratingModels.push(element);
                    }
                    resolve(ratingModels);
                },
                error => alert('RatingRangeDataPromise(' + firstResult + ', ' + maxResults + ') Data not available. Please try again.\n' + error),
                () => {
                });
        });
    }

    getRatingForJobRange(firstResult: number, maxResults: number, jobId: number): Promise<RatingModel[]> {
        return new Promise<RatingModel[]>(resolve => {
            this.getRatingRangeForJobHttpCall(firstResult, maxResults, jobId).subscribe(
                data => {
                    var ratingModels: RatingModel[] = [];
                    for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
                        var element = data[index];
                        ratingModels.push(element);
                    }
                    resolve(ratingModels);
                },
                error => alert('RatingForJobRange(' + firstResult + ', ' + maxResults + ', ' + jobId + ') Data not available. Please try again.\n' + error),
                () => {
                });
        });
    }

    saveRating(ratingModel: RatingModel): Promise<RatingModel> {
        return new Promise<RatingModel>(resolve => {
            this.saveRatingHttpCall(ratingModel).subscribe(
                data => {
                    resolve(data);
                },
                error => alert('Save Unsuccesfull.\n' + error),
                () => {

                });
        });
    }

    getRating(id: number): Promise<RatingModel> {
        return new Promise<RatingModel>(resolve => {
            this.getRatingHttpCall(id).subscribe(
                data => {
                    resolve(data);
                },
                error => alert('getRating Data not available. Please try again.\n' + error),
                () => {
                    //console.log("Finished getRating");
                });
        });
    }

    public getRatingRangeHttpCall(firstResult: number, maxResults: number) {
        return this.http.get(this.BASE_URI + '/list/range/' + firstResult + '/' + maxResults)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    public getRatingRangeForJobHttpCall(firstResult: number, maxResults: number, jobId: number) {
        return this.http.get(this.BASE_URI + '/list/range/' + firstResult + '/' + maxResults + '/' + jobId)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    public saveRatingHttpCall(ratingModel: RatingModel) {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.post(this.BASE_URI + '/save', ratingModel, {
            headers: headers
        })
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    public getRatingHttpCall(id: number) {
        return this.http.get(this.BASE_URI + '/list/' + id)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

}
```

**parentService.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class ParentService {

    public PARENT_BASE_URI: string = 'http://localhost:8080/jbosswildfly';
    //public PARENT_BASE_URI: string = 'http://jbosswildfly-easypeasy.rhcloud.com';

    constructor() {

    }

    public getBaseUrl(): string {
        return this.PARENT_BASE_URI;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have changed the code to the following, I will test it to see if it works:

```
  providers: [
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}, 
    { provide: RatingService, useClass: RatingService}, 
    { provide: JobService, useClass: JobService}, 
    { provide: UtilityService, useClass: UtilityService}
  ]
```

Comment: shouldnt the `{provide: .. useClass..` be closed with a `}`? (not sure, haven't used it this way mysefl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

should be :

```
providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, 
useClass: IonicErrorHandler}, 
RatingService,
JobService, 
UtilityService,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this error if you accidentally use

```
import RatingService from '../pages/service/ratingService';
```

instead of

```
import { RatingService } from '../pages/service/ratingService';
```

That typo cost me 2 hours so I'm adding this answer in the hope that it saves someone else the same frustration.